# Why isn't a device token being generated?

Tags: react-native, devicetoken, react-native-push-notification

I'm trying to use **react-native-push-notifications**, and I've been stuck on this for a good few days now, and I just can't find a way to get it to work.
I know it's been brought up a few times over the years, with varying degrees of success, and I've tried all of the 'solutions', but with no luck.

**NB... I haven't tried it on iOS yet, so this is mostly an Android issue.**

I have followed the instructions, and searched the trouble shooting, but I cannot get the device token from `onRegister`.

I can get a local notification to fire on load, and `onNotification` is being called upon interaction, but no token.

I'm not sure how relevant this is, but I thought I'd have to give permission(?), but even though `requestPermissions` is true, I never get asked. I did a little digging, and in `node_modules\react-native-push-notification\index.js` there are two functions requesting permissions.

This is getting called automatically and has the correct senderID

```
// Prevent requestPermissions called twice if ios result is pending
Notifications._requestPermissions
```

This only gets called if I explicitly call `PushNotifications.requestPermissions()` but the senderID is undefined

```
// Stock requestPermissions function
Notifications.requestPermissions
```

I've tried lots of different combinations of adding or removing lines from Gradle and the Manifest, but nothing's worked, so I've started again with just the lines from the documentation.
Originally, I had the call to `configurePushNotifications()` in my logIn function, but read that it should be called from the highest component before loading the JS, so i moved it to `index.js`, but it didn't make any difference, still no token.

I'm literally at my wits end, and could really do with some help please, there's a Ferrero Rocher Easter egg up for grabs for whoever solves it!

Thanks xxx

- Testing on Windows
- Android Device, *not emulator*
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.59.5
- react-native-push-notification": ^3.1.3,

## **AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.myApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
            android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
                    android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
                    android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@android:color/white"/>

        <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
        <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
                android:exported="true"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->

        <!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
        <service
                android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerServiceGcm"
                android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- </ Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->

        <!-- < Else > -->
        <service
                android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
                android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- </Else> -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## **app\build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sumoshift"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1") {
        force = true
    }
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1") {
        force = true
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

## **android\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

## **notifications.js**

```
configurePushNotifications(shouldRegisterDeviceDetails) {
        console.log('notifications Notification configurePushNotifications');

        Notification.create({message: 'Test message working'});

        PushNotification.configure({

            // (optional) called when Token is generated (Android & iOS)
            onRegister:  function (registrationToken) {
                console.log('notifications Notification configurePushNotifications onRegister registrationToken: ', registrationToken);

                if (shouldRegisterDeviceDetails) {
                    console.log('registering device');

                    API.editShifterData(8, {
                        device_token: registrationToken.token,
                        phone_type: registrationToken.os
                    })
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.log('notifications Notification configurePushNotifications onRegister response: ', response);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log('notifications Notification configurePushNotifications onRegister error: ', error);
                        })
                }
            },


            // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
            onNotification: function (notification) {
                console.log('notifications Notification configurePushNotifications onNotification notification: ', notification);

                if (notification.userInteraction) {
                    console.log('notifications Notification configurePushNotifications onNotification userInteraction TRUE');

                    Notification.open(notification);
                } else {
                    console.log('notifications Notification configurePushNotifications onNotification userInteraction FALSE');

                    Notification.create(notification);
                }
            },

            // ANDROID ONLY: GCM Sender ID (optional - not required for local notifications, but is need to receive remote push notifications)
            senderID: "xxxxxxxxxxx",

            // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
            permissions: {
                alert: true,
                badge: true,
                sound: true
            },

            // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
            // default: true
            popInitialNotification: true,

            /**
             * (optional) default: true
             * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
             * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
             */
            requestPermissions: true,
        });
    }
```

Thanks again xxx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone runs into the same issue, I had to add some extra lines to the Manifest that weren't mentioned in the package's documentation.

```
<receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher"/>
<receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
```

I'll be totally honest though, looking at the issues section of the package on NPM, it seems like there's so much that hasn't been mentioned, and there are lots of different solutions from different people, so while this is what I used to get it to work, it's a bit of a free for all.

Good luck!

Comment: @VishalGoel - Hi! If you're using Xcode, remember to enable push notifications in the 'Capabilities' tab.

Comment: Actually i testing on simulator. Token was generated on real device.